# PR2 simulation keeps glitching/jumping in RVIZ when using /odom_combined as fixed frame

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm relatively new to ROS. I'm trying to run the PR2 robot on ROS Kinect for Ubuntu 16.04. I'm using the MoveIt stack and launching the following nodes:

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch

roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2.launch

roslaunch pr2_moveit_config demo.launch
```

Which resulted in this:
https://youtu.be/OnN2UppZ3r8

The glitching starts almost immediately as the robot starts jumping up and down with its torso. I saw that the the torso link was receiving mixed messages some sent by the robot_state_publisher. I commented out the robot_state_publisher node from the demo.launch:

```
<launch

  <arg name="db" default="false" />
  <arg name="debug" default="false" />

  <include file="$(find pr2_moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch">
    <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true"/>
  </include>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="virtual_joint_broadcaster_0" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom_combined base_footprint 100" />

<!--   <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
    <rosparam param="/source_list">[/move_group/fake_controller_joint_states]</rosparam>
  </node>
 -->  
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="true" output="screen" />

  <include file="$(find pr2_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch">
    <arg name="allow_trajectory_execution" value="true"/>
    <arg name="fake_execution" value="true"/>
    <arg name="info" value="true"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
  </include>

  <include file="$(find pr2_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
    <arg name="config" value="true"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
  </include>

  <include file="$(find pr2_moveit_config)/launch/default_warehouse_db.launch" if="$(arg db)"/>

</launch>
```

which stopped the torso jumping but would still glitch when I moved the base forward:
https://youtu.be/k5mpx9RLZTw

The glitching stops when I change the global fixed frame to /base_link but then the octomap does not update properly as it doesn't perceive the robot as moving. The octomap did however work when using /odom_combined.

Any advice on how to approach this issue and for any more information needed to understand the problem please ask and I will happily provide it. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307586/pr2-simulation-keeps-glitching/jumping-in-rviz-when-using-/odom_combined-as-fixed-frame/) by [benwex93](https://answers.ros.org/users/38364/benwex93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-11-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-04**:\

> I'm using the MoveIt stack and launching the following nodes:

can you clarify why you start all three of those launch files?

**Comment by [benwex93](https://answers.ros.org/users/38364/benwex93/) on 2018-11-04**:
I'm trying to create a teleoperation system for the pr2. I'm launching

1. a custom world I made (I edited it to the empty_world.launch file since I get the same behavior there as well)
2. the pr2 node to initialize the pr2 and place it in the world
3. the moveit node for the pr2 so that I can

**Comment by [benwex93](https://answers.ros.org/users/38364/benwex93/) on 2018-11-04**:
control the pr2 arms from within RVIZ using the interactive markers. I also want the octomap to work so that the robot can map out the environment because later I will need that input later for an AI application

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-04**:
Just to clarify: you're starting *launch files*, which will start multiple nodes. If any of those launch files start the same nodes, especially things that publish `JointState` msgs or TF frames, the "glitching" that you describe can happen.

It's not actually glitching, the visualisation ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-04**:
.. is just provided with conflicting information (from the human point of view, that is) and visualises what it receives.

Hence my question: how did you come up with that set of launch files.

**Comment by [benwex93](https://answers.ros.org/users/38364/benwex93/) on 2018-11-04**:
I followed http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/StartingPR2Simulation for the first 2 nodes and I followed http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/ros_visualization/visualization_tutorial.html#step-1-launch-the-demo-and-configure-the-plugin
for the 3rd node

**Comment by [benwex93](https://answers.ros.org/users/38364/benwex93/) on 2018-11-04**:
I guess I kind of assumed they would work together. When I launched just the empty world and pr2_moveit_config without pr2.launch it doesn't insert the pr2 into gazebo. Is there any way I can figure out how to allow these nodes to run without conflicting each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so @gvhoorm helped point me in the right direction, the launch files indeed initialized nodes that sent conflicting information, for example to the /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined topic. So I commented out the robot_ekf node for the pr2_bringup.launch file in pr2_gazebo and  the glitching stopped. Now there is no /robot_pose_ekf topic being published (since there was no robot_pose_ekf node in demo.launch either) and I hope there will be no side effects from this but everything seems to be working.

```
<launch>
  
  <!-- Controller Manager -->
  <include file="$(find pr2_controller_manager)/controller_manager.launch" />

  <!-- Fake Calibration -->
  <node pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" name="fake_joint_calibration"
        args="pub /calibrated std_msgs/Bool true" />

  <!-- Stereo image processing -->
  <include file="$(find pr2_gazebo)/config/dualstereo_camera.launch" />

  <!-- Start image_proc inside camera namespace-->
  <include file="$(find pr2_gazebo)/config/r_forearm_cam.launch" />
  <include file="$(find pr2_gazebo)/config/l_forearm_cam.launch" />

  <!-- diagnostics aggregator -->
  <node pkg="diagnostic_aggregator" type="aggregator_node" name="diag_agg" args="Robot" />
  <group ns="diag_agg">
    <include file="$(find pr2_gazebo)/config/pr2_analyzers_simple.launch" />
    <!--
    <include file="$(find pr2_gazebo)/config/pr2_analyzers.launch" />
    -->
  </group>

  <!-- Dashboard aggregation -->
  <node pkg="pr2_dashboard_aggregator" type="dashboard_aggregator.py" name="pr2_dashboard_aggregator"/>

  <!-- Robot pose ekf -->
 <!-- <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf" output="screen">
    <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
    <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
    <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
    <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
    <remap from="odom" to="base_odometry/odom" />
    <remap from="imu_data" to="torso_lift_imu/data" />
  </node>
-->
  <!-- Base Laser dynamic_reconfigure -->
  <node pkg="gazebo_plugins" type="hokuyo_node" name="base_hokuyo_node">
    <param name="port" type="string" value="/etc/ros/sensors/base_hokuyo" />
    <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="base_laser_link" />
    <param name="min_ang" type="double" value="-2.2689" />
    <param name="max_ang" type="double" value="2.2689" />
    <param name="skip" type="int" value="1" />
    <param name="intensity" value="false" />
  </node>

  <!-- Tilt Laser dynamic_reconfigure -->
  <node pkg="gazebo_plugins" type="hokuyo_node" name="tilt_hokuyo_node">
    <param name="port" type="string" value="/etc/ros/sensors/tilt_hokuyo" />
    <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="laser_tilt_link" />
    <param name="min_ang" type="double" value="-0.829" />
    <param name="max_ang" type="double" value="0.829" />
    <param name="skip" type="int" value="1" />
    <param name="intensity" value="true" />
  </node>

  <!-- Buffer Server -->
  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="buffer_server" name="tf2_buffer_server" output="screen">
    <param name="buffer_size" value="120.0"/>
  </node>

  <!-- Spawns the synchronizer -->
  <node type="camera_synchronizer" name="camera_synchronizer_node" pkg="gazebo_plugins" output="screen" />

  <!-- testing only: simulate torso counter weight spring to reduce load on the torso joint
  <node name="simulate_torso_spring" pkg="pr2_gazebo" type="pr2_simulate_torso_spring.py" respawn="false" output="screen" />
  -->

</launch>
```

what also works is to comment out:

```
 <!-- <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="virtual_joint_broadcaster_0" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom_combined base_footprint 100" />-->

  <!--<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
    <rosparam param="/source_list">[/move_group/fake_controller_joint_states]</rosparam>
  </node>
  -->
```

from the demo.launch file of moveit, it seems these are the two sections conflicting with each other and sending out conflicting messages about the robot pose.

---

Originally posted by [benwex93](https://answers.ros.org/users/38364/benwex93/) with karma: 51 on 2018-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0